# R - Element from datatable "a" matches the column name of datatable "b" inside column creation not recognized as column names

Tags: r, class, data.table

I want to create a new column in a datatable, using something like `dt[, x:= y * z]`.

However, the `y` I'm using comes from an element from another datatable: `dt2$xxx[1]`.

But it seems that even if `dt2$xxx[1]` matches to the column name in `dt`, R does not recognize `dt2$xxx[1]` and output it as a factor which could not be calculated.

Here is a dummy example:

```
recipe = data.table(food = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "a", "c", "l", "k", "o"),
                    ingredient = c(rep("sugar",5), rep("water",5), rep("honey",5)),
                    value = c(1:15))

record = data.table(date = c(rep("2018-04-27", 10)),
                    a = c(sample(1:10, 10)),
                    b = c(sample(1:10, 10)))
record[,sugar:= recipe$food[1]*recipe$value[1] + recipe$food[2]*recipe$value[2]]
```

This gives the error saying that factors cannot go into the calculation, but I thought `recipe$food[1]` (which is "a") will be treated as a column in `record` which could be calculated column-wise into the function.

I don't understand the class properties behind and how to fix this problem, would be awesome if someone can help me, thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please follow : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is too difficult, even impossible, to help you without some data. I'm getting you have a data called `dt`, which at least has a column named `z` and want to produce a new column called `x` wich is the result of multiplying `z` times a number `y` that is the first element of column `xxx` of data.table `dt2`. Is that right? if so, could you please share some dummy data and at least show the rsults of `str(df)` and `str(df2)`?

Comment: @PavoDive Thank you so much for the reply!!
Yes you are right about what I mean.
I've included the dummy example in the question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example, may be we need

```
r1 <- dcast(recipe[food %in% names(record)[2:3]], ingredient ~ food)
record[, sugar := a * r1$a + b * r1$b]
```

#### Update

With the new data, we can do

```
r1 <- dcast(recipe[food %in% names(record)[2:3]], ingredient ~ food, fill = 0)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(r1))) record[, (r1$ingredient[i]) := 
              a * r1$a[i] + b * r1$b[i]][]
```

#### Update2

If we need to make it more dynamic based on the column names, there are two options

Create a vector of column names that we need to multiply

```
nm1 <- names(record)[-1]
```

and then use one of the following methods

**1)** with `Reduce/Map`

```
for(i in seq_along(r1)) record[, (r1$ingredient[i]) :=  Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, .SD, 
           r1[i, nm1, with = FALSE])), .SDcols = nm1][]
```

**2)** with `crossprod`

```
for(i in seq_along(r1)) record[,(r1$ingredient[i]) :=  
   as.vector(as.matrix(.SD) %*% unlist(r1[i, nm1, with = FALSE])), .SDcols = nm1][]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it worked for the example.
However, I'm sorry that I have not state the situation more clearly, in the real case there are more than one ingredient, which I've updated in the example. In this case it would it more difficult, right?

Comment: @ThomasSun Sorry for the late response.  was busy with other stuff.  Can you check the updated answer

Comment: Allow me to bother you one last time...
I guess until now you fully understand what I'm trying to do: use the ingredient table to match transactional data (which is recorded with the unit of cups).
However, since in the real situation, the amount of food is abundant (a, b, c, d, and so on), is there a programatic way I can write the last line for them? (a * r1$a[i] + b * r1$b[i])

Comment: This works amazingly.... thank you so much!!
Is there any way I could do on this platform to credit you besides marking this as the answer? As this is my first question posted haha
Anyways, many thanks!

Comment: @ThomasSun Glad to know that it works for you.  It's all I wanted, nothing more, nothing less :=)